# Jersey Logging filter eats UserPrincipal for POST

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I have created a LoggingFilter for Jersey and have it configured correctly in the web.xml.  All works fine.  When I do a "GET" I get the userPrincipal (request.getUserPrincipal()) but for a POST it returns null.  I have written several REST services in java 1.4 on Websphere and could always get to the userPrincipal, but on Tomcat/1.6 I get the above.  I am using Basic Auth. Is Jersey doing this? Or Tomcat?

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Lookup Resources</web-resource-name>
        <description>A set of secured resources.</description>
        <url-pattern>/rest/lookup/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>DataServ_Lookup</role-name>
        <role-name>DataServ_Admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <!-- Comment this out for Dev.  It is a MUST for Prod... 
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>-->

</security-constraint>
```

Comment: `UserPrincipal` is set by the Web Container (not Jersey). Can you share your `web.xml` (section relevant to authentication) and `context.xml` (relevant to valves)? Also you can analyse headers sent to Web Server using Firebug for example: if browser does not send authentication information, `UserPrincipal` won't be present.

Comment: I assume that, since authentication is being achieved, that the credentials were passed in.  Or is that too big of an assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cudos to dma_k for leading me to my own insanity.  As you can see above, there is no security constraint on the POST!

I needed to add:`<http-method>POST</http-method>`.  Doh!

Comment: Great that you've found the solution yourself :) BTW, not listing any `<http-method>` will enable all methods.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you create your own LoggingFilter? Did you know Jersey includes one out of the box?
Is your filter modifying the request in any way? Try injecting HttpServletRequest to your resource and get principal form that - see if it is set. If not, see if your request really contains the basic auth header.

Comment: The out of the box logger does not log what I want it to and it it quite verbose.  The filter does not modify the request any differently for GET or POST.  It is being set, as GET has it.  I never thought of getting the header itself.  I will try that, although I will have to figure that out also..  Thanks for the idea!